# Sublime; AttributeError: module 'googlesearch' has no attribute 'search'

Tags: python, sublimetext3

So I'm trying to use python to do web scraping. I started here using [this](https://breakingcode.wordpress.com/2010/06/29/google-search-python/) tutorial and it all worked fine using python from the command line

as shown here

[web scraping using google search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrM5d.png)

however when I try to run that same code in sublime text 3 I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "H:\Gits\googlesearch.py", line 2, in <module>
import googlesearch 
   File "H:\Gits\googlesearch.py", line 3, in <module>
for url in googlesearch.search('"Breaking Code" WordPress blog', stop=20):
AttributeError: module 'googlesearch' has no attribute 'search'
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
[cmd: ['C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/pkgs/python-3.6.6-hea74fb7_0/python.exe', 
'-u', 'H:\\Gits\\googlesearch.py']]
[dir: H:\Gits]
[path: 
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\mingw- 
w64\bin;
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\usr\bin;
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\bin;
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts;
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.0\bin;
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.0\libnvvp;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Razer Chroma SDK\bin;
C:\Program Files\Razer Chroma SDK\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;
C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;
C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;
C:\Program 
Files\Git\cmd;C:\Users\delengowski\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;
C:\WINDOWS\system32;
C:\WINDOWS;
C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;
C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
C:\Program Files\HDF_Group\HDF5\1.10.1\bin\;
C:\Program Files\PuTTY\;
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2018a\runtime\win64;
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2018a\bin;
C:\MinGW\bin;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Wolfram Research\WolframScript\;
C:\Program Files\doxygen\bin;
C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;
C:\Users\delengowski\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;
C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin;
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\pkgs\python-3.6.4-h6538335_1;
C:\texlive\2017\bin\win32;
C:\MinGW\bin;
c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages;]
```

I am using python 3.6 through Anaconda, and I am building my python using this build setting

```
{
    "cmd": ["C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\python.exe", "-u", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python",
    "env" :
        {
        "PYTHONPATH": "C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\Lib"
        }
}
```

In sublime I have both Anaconda and Conda packages installed

I can build simple python scripts using this build setting just fine, for example like a simple

```
print("Hello World")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script is named `googlesearch.py`, so when you do `import googlesearch`, you're getting your own script instead of the real googlesearch package module.

Name your script something other than `googlesearch.py`.

Comment: Good point, that was poor on my part. However, that did not fix the issue, I am still getting the same error.

Comment: You probably have a leftover file named `googlesearch.pyc`.  Remove it.

Comment: ive deleted everything with googlesearch in its name except for under Anaconda3 on my hard drive and now I am "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'googlesearch'

Comment: Did you install that module?  If so, how did you do it?

Comment: Yes I have. As I mentioned in the OP, I can get this code to build just fine if I go to command line and start up python that. However, building it from ST3, I am having issues.  I did "pip install google" in a cmd window run as admin. It is located in C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages

Comment: Is ST3 using Anaconda3, or is it using some other installed version of Python?  Run this code to find out: `import sys; print (sys.version)`

Comment: 3.6.6 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Jun 28 2018, 11:27:44) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]

Comment: It looks like `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages` is not in your `PYTHONPATH`.  (`\Lib` is, but not `\Lib\site-packages`).

Comment: You were right, there was additional problems. The build file I had open and was editing was the wrong version or something. I created a new build system and it worked. Thanks.

Comment: If you want to type up the new answer and ill select it. Or Ill just choose this as the correct.